# Queue a Google Play app to download later on wifi to save mobile data?

Tags: google-play-store, wi-fi, mobile-data

Is there a method to queue a new app for installation from Google Play, so that it downloads later when the phone connects to WiFi? The point being to save mobile data.

Comment: Is this for a new app installation, or for an existing app to update?

Comment: You can add them you wish list

Comment: @Alexander the great: that will just add an app to the list, but will not install it.

Comment: @Chahk this would be for a new app installation

Comment: I was just writing up a similar question. Perhaps this is a feature that should be requested? Also, I have Tasker and was wondering if this would be possible using it.

Answer (score 1):

For an update to an existing app, you just have to enable that in Google play's settings. For a newly installed app, I don't think it is possible. You can block the  background data for Google play, but that's just a workaround and it has limitations like you won't be able to make in-app purchases when you are on mobile network.